# compare "array of words" against textarea with php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I asked this question yesterday: [Compare array of words to a textarea input with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495735/compare-array-of-words-to-a-textarea-input-with-javascript)

Now I want to do the same thing with php...

Is there any easy code for this?

Thanks

UPDATE: I would like to test the textarea input against the array, and if match of bad words found, die();

Thanks

Comment: Do the exact same things suggested in the javascript question. Learn to understand principles instead of just copypasta

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would post the full question rather than simply posting a link. 

Also, do you want to filter out the 'bad' words or do you want to test if there are ANY bad words and then have it fail validation? And if it fails validation do you need to tell them which words failed?

Comment: ok sorry Noah, I want to test if there are any bad words... Then fail or "die()" as it is called in php.

Comment: Please update the body of your question. While I appreciate the response, It is again more helpful if everyone can see edits to your question directly rather than having to search through comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bad_words = array('first','second','third');

$posted = str_ireplace($bad_words, '****', $posted);
```

This will replace bad words with '****'

**EDIT:**

to check if any of words from bad_words exist in a string:

```
foreach( $bad_words as $bad ){
 if( stristr($posted, $bad) !== FALSE )
 {
  $contains_bad_words = TRUE;
 }    
}
```

Comment: actually i was looking for an if statement where I cancel the entire operation if bad words was found. thanks alot though

Comment: Also, any way of making this case INsensetive?

Comment: What I mean is to make  the match if "Bad" "BAD" "bad" when only "bad" is in the array...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$bad_words = array('ring','sarah','chuck');

$intersect = array_intersect(explode(' ', strtolower($_POST['textarea'])), $bad_words);

if(count($intersect)) die('You should wash your mouth out with soap!');
```

The array_intersect will compare the two different arrays of words and return all of the values that exist in both arrays. Therefore if count($intersect) is anything but 0 (evaluated as a false in this case) then you can exist the script and output an error.