# I want to check the content of textarea must contains previous inputs' words using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, textarea

Is it possible to check the content of textarea must contain previous inputs' all words using javascript or jquery? and if not contains all words than the value of textarea is invalid or will not submit.
Please reply me soon.

Thanks.

Comment: i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495735/compare-array-of-words-to-a-textarea-input-with-javascript but it not works i want the same which is mentioned here.

Comment: can you add some of your code to the question?

Comment: <script>
var value1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('name2').value;
var value35 = document.getElementById('name35').value;

var bad_words = new Array(value1, value2, .., value35); // watered down
                      
var user_words = document.getElementById('final').split(" ");
 $("#final-submit").click(function (e) {   
for( var i in bad_words)
{
  if( user_words.indexOf( bad_words[i] ) != -1 )
  {
    alert( 'The textarea has bad word!');
    break;
  }
}
      
 });                    
 </script>

Comment: user must type those 35 input words in textarea which are previously given as an values of those 35 inputs

Comment: Alright, check out the edited answer. It checks against an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what it is you're trying to get done: You want the user to utilize the previously given input of 35 words which is retrieved from input fields, but also give the user the option to add more. This addition is optional.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2et0863h/9/)

**To be clear**

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 1, 2, 3 | returns true

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 1, 2, 3, 4 | returns true

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 1, 3, 2 | returns true

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 3, 2, 1 | returns true

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 2, 2, 1 | returns false

input: 1, 2, 3 | textarea: 1, 2    | returns false

**JS**

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", true);

$(".input").on("keyup", function () {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
    var finalinput1 = input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput2 = input1 + " " + input3 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput3 = input2 + " " + input1 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput4 = input2 + " " + input3 + " " + input1;
    var finalinput5 = input3 + " " + input1 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput6 = input3 + " " + input2 + " " + input1;
});



$("#area").on("keyup", function () {
    var content2 = $("#area").val();
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
    var finalinput1 = input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput2 = input1 + " " + input3 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput3 = input2 + " " + input1 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput4 = input2 + " " + input3 + " " + input1;
    var finalinput5 = input3 + " " + input1 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput6 = input3 + " " + input2 + " " + input1;
    if (content2.indexOf(finalinput1) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput2) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput3) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput4) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput5) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput6) >= 0) {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

$("#submit").click(function () {
    var content2 = $("#area").val();
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
    var finalinput1 = input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput2 = input1 + " " + input3 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput3 = input2 + " " + input1 + " " + input3;
    var finalinput4 = input2 + " " + input3 + " " + input1;
    var finalinput5 = input3 + " " + input1 + " " + input2;
    var finalinput6 = input3 + " " + input2 + " " + input1;
    if (content2.indexOf(finalinput1) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput2) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput3) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput4) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput5) >= 0 || content2.indexOf(finalinput6) >= 0) {
        $("#output").text("Succes!");
    } else {
        $("#output").text("Values are not the same!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80824/discussion-on-answer-by-theonlyerror-i-want-to-check-the-content-of-textarea-mus).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can access the value of the textareas inner text by accessing the value.

Ex: `document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Fifth Avenue, New York City";`

You can then check this as you would any other JavaScript and on submit run the tests

Comment: okay i got this but i am basic at javascript so if possible can you provide me the code. as user must utilize previous 35 inputs for textarea statement else it can not submit textarea value.

Answer (score 0):

This will check the value of the text entered on each keyup event against the value you define. If that returns true the submit property will not be disabled, otherwise it will be.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $("textarea").on("keyup", function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'value to check against'){
       $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , false);
       }
    else{
       $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , true);
       }
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgdogf2c/

If checking for an item in an array:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $("textarea").on("keyup", function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).val(), [ "one", "two", "three"] ) != -1){
       $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , false);
    }else{
       $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled' , true);
       }
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz2q6zga/1/

Comment: pretty much similar but not what i want. i want user must utilize all previous inputs in textarea . and it can add any other text also but the previous inputs value are necessary for submission of textarea statement.